# Bubble Sort C Programming

Tags: c, sorting

Hey folks ive come across another problem.
Im trying to do a bubble sort and a selection sort ive got my selection sort working.
But im having trouble with my bubble sort.Here it is.

```
void sortBubble(int nRow, char sArr[5][10], char sArrTemp[10]) {
    int nSwaps=0;
    while(nSwaps==1) {
        nSwaps=0;
        for(nRow=1;nRow <5;nRow++) {
            if(strcmp(sArr[nRow-1],sArr[nRow])<0) {
                puts("Doing Swap");
                strcpy(sArrTemp,sArr[nRow]);
                strcpy(sArr[nRow],sArr[nRow-1]);
                strcpy(sArr[nRow-1],sArrTemp);
                nSwaps=1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas why its not working.

Comment: What part isn't working?

Comment: You will never enter the outer loop. Besides being pretty obvious by just looking at the first two lines of the function body, it would have been even more obvious if you tried to step through the code line by line in a debugger. A debugger is one of your most valuable tools as a programmer. Use it whenever there is something that doesn't seem to work the way is should.

Comment: A `main` with a test case could very very helpful.

Comment: I've changed the while loop but how do I do a sort with a swap function. Thsnks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    int nSwaps=0;
    while(nSwaps==1) {
     // sort
    }
```

change nSwaps to 1 and it should work...

```
int nSwaps=1;
while(nSwaps==1) {
 // sort
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You never enter the loop because of

```
int nSwaps=0;
```

Also, you should consider using another algorithm for sorting.
I would recommend [qsort](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_qsort.htm)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is

`int nSwaps= 0 ;
while(nSwaps== 1 )`

so

0==1 which is return 0(false) so you never enter the loop try to change it